# How to add data to an object that comes from a JSON file

Tags: javascript

I have an object with values. There are other values ​​in a separate json file. I use fetch() to fetch values. I need to add to my object with values, the values ​​that came from the file. How can i do this?

```js
const values = {
  valueTitle1: value1,
  valueTitle2: value2,
  valueTitle3: value3,
};


const jsonData = "values.json";
async function getResponse(json) {
  const request = await fetch(json);
  if (request.ok) {
    const response = await request.json();
    return response;
  } else {
    console.error("Server is not response");
  }
}

const responseJson = getResponse(jsonData);

const data = responseJson.then((data) => {

});
```

```js
{
  "values": [{
      "valueTitle3": value3
    },
    {
      "valueTitle4": value4
    },
    {
      "valueTitle5": value5
    }
  ]
}
```

I need a result like this:

```js
const values = {
  valueTitle1: value1,
  valueTitle2: value2,
  valueTitle3: value3,
  valueTitle4: value4,
  valueTitle5: value5,
  valueTitle6: value6,
};
```

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: if you need to merge objects: `let merged = {...values, ...json};`

Comment: Your `getResponse` function is not returning promise

Comment: @kennarddh yes because json() returns a promise.

Comment: Your function await the `json` function and return the object.

Comment: `getResponse` is an async function. therefore it will always return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

```
const responseJson = getResponse(jsonData);

return responseJson.then((responsData) => {
    return responsData[yourValue] = 'Your Value';
});
```

You can try smth like this.
But in this case, the function will return a promise, so you should handle it using 'then'

Or

```
const responseJson = await getResponse(jsonData);

responsData[yourValue] = 'Your Value';
```

But you must use this code inside 'async' function

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
const values = {
  valueTitle1: value1,
  valueTitle2: value2,
  valueTitle3: value3,
};

const jsonData = "values.json";
async function getResponse(json) {
  const request = await fetch(json);
  if (request.ok) {
    const response = await request.json();
    return response;
  } else {
    console.error("Server is not response");
  }
}

const responseJson = getResponse(jsonData);


responseJson.then(({values: v}) => {
    v.forEach(value => Object.assign(values, value))
    console.log(values)
});
```

output:

```
{valueTitle1: 'value1', valueTitle2: 'value2', valueTitle3: 'value3', valueTitle4: 'value4', valueTitle5: 'value5'}
```